# c - To know the aspect size of a two-dimensional dynamic array

Tags: c, malloc, calloc

I am now implementing deep learning in C.
I want to know the horizontal and vertical lengths of the two-dimensional dynamic array created with any length.

My attempt:

```
    double** a1 = createArray(?, ?);
    size_t a1_size = _msize(*a1)/sizeof(double);
```

createArray function:

```
double** createArray(int l, int m){
    double **result;

    result = calloc(sizeof(double*), l);
    result[0] = calloc(sizeof(double), l * m);
    for (int i = 1; i < l; ++i) result[i] = result[i - 1] + m;

    return result;
}
```

I tried to solve this using the _msize function but failed.

Can you tell the horizontal and vertical sizes of the two-dimensional dynamic array? Can you help me?

Comment: You cannot get the size of dynamically allocated memory from the pointer alone. You need to keep track of that yourself by storing the dimensions.

Comment: @kaylum: Re “You cannot get the size of dynamically allocated memory from the pointer alone”: `_msize` is a Microsoft extension that gets the size of dynamically allocated memory from the pointer alone. (Unfortunately for OP, I expect it gets the amount of memory that was allocated, not the amount of memory that was requested, although the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/msize?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170) is unclear.)

Comment: Try `_msize(a1)/sizeof a1[0]` and `_msize(a1[0])/sizeof a1[0][0]`.  What do you get?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Wow! That's the answer I wanted, can you explain how it works?

Comment: @Hanyechan `_msize(ptr)` returns   the byte size of the allocation (see [@Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72592007/c-to-know-the-aspect-size-of-a-two-dimensional-dynamic-array?noredirect=1#comment128230374_72592007) note).  `sizeof ptr[0]` is the byte size of the referenced object.  `_msize(ptr)/sizeof ptr[0]`, hopefully, is the object allocation count.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thank you! It is easy to understand.